# Welches Wort passt gut zur folgenden Situation

Tags: single-word-request

Ich beschreibe die Situation mit einem Beispiel.

z.B. Ich und einer meiner Kollegen sprechen darüber, wie man das Produkt verbessern kann. Er empfiehlt mir etwas und ich mag seine Empfehlung nicht und empfehle dagegen etwas anderes (oder umgekehrt).

Wenn ich nun anderen diese Situation beschreibe, dann sage ich, dass ich mit dem Kollegen diskutiert habe. Diejenigen, die nicht bei der Produktverbesserung dabei waren, verstehen das aber falsch. Sie denken, dass wir irgendwie gekämpft haben.

Welches Wort würde in dieser Situation besser passen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tatsächlich ist "diskutiert" **genau** das richtige Wort.

Diskutieren hat keinerlei negative Konnotationen. Wenn jemand eine "Diskussion" als "Streitgespräch" interpretiert, dann ist das seine Fehlinterpretation.

Möglicherweise kannst Du die "Wirkung" des Wortes durch ein "miteinander" abschwächen, um die falsche Interpretation von Vorneherein zu verhindern.

Der Satz:

> Wir haben miteinander diskutiert...

wird vermutlich häufiger als "konstruktiv" wahrgenommen als der Satz:

> Wir haben diskutiert...

Aber der Unterschied ist wirklich nur marginal, und auch der zweite Satz ist vollkommen neutral und bedeutet eben **nicht** automatisch, dass Ihr gestritten habt.

Comment: sehr guter Hinweis (miteinander). Jemand hat mir "fachsimpeln" empfohlen aber in den Wörterbüchern ist seine Bedeutung anders. Passt "fachsimpeln" zu dieser Situation?

Comment: nein, denn fachsimpeln ist nur ein Gespräch über ein fachliches Thema, z.B. Technik oder Literatur. Es müssen keine gegensätzlichen Positionen vorkommen, also keine Diskussion.

Comment: +1 für das "miteinander"

Comment: Die Bedeutung von *fachsimpeln* ist auch eher "Allgemeines Plaudern über ein fachliches Thema" und zielt in keinster Weise auf eine "Problemlösung"

Comment: Wenn man noch bedenkt, dass im Berufsleben Diskussionen alltäglich sind, ist es umso erstaunlicher, dass dies als Streitgespräch interpretiert werden kann. Anders sähe es im privaten Umfeld aus. Die Aussage "Ich habe mit meiner Frau/meinem Mann diskutiert", ohne weiteren Kontext, könnte durchaus auf ein Streitgespräch hindeuten.

Comment: Vielen dank für eure Antworten. Was ich verstanden habe ist ich muss mehr detail geben, wenn ich das Verb "diskutieren", weil es anderen nicht sehr klar ist, was ich gemeint habe. Aus dem Grund können sie meinen Satz anders interpretieren.

Comment: Weder Streitgespräche, noch Diskussionen, sind an sich negativ oder positiv und beides ist auch mehr oder weniger das selbe. Ob man das positiv oder negativ bewertet hängt, wie so oft, vom Kontext ab. Beides kann sehr zivilisiert und konstruktiv sein, beides kann schrill und destruktiv sein. Fachsimpeln kann man ohne gegensätzliche Positionen einzunehmen, etwa in dem man noch einen Aspekt anspricht, und noch einen oder immer tiefer in die Details eindringt.